# Whats the equivalent to a PC ctrl+click on a Mac

Tags: windows, mac

I'm trying to select multiple things in a list on a Mac. Shift+click works the same but I can't figure out how to select noncontiguous things. Most of my internet searching shows equivalences from a Mac user's perspective.  I spent a few minutes with Bing, then Google,  surprised I haven't been able to find this.

Answer (score 1):

Shift/click selects contiguous items, Cmd/click discontiguous.
You can combine the two to make large & small selections. I don't have a screen recorder that can show keys held whilst I do this to show you, but as an example…

If you start with a list of files in a folder; click the first, shift-click the third, then Cmd/click the fifth & finally Shift/click the seventh.
You will then have 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 selected, with 4 missed out.